# How to insert <br> after label tag in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), I have a simple input like this:

```
<%= f.input :email %>
```

This generates (removed irrelevant parts):

```
...
  <label>Email</label>
  <input .... />
...
```

I want the input control to come below the label, so I need a `<br/>` after `</label>`:

```
...
  <label>Email</label>
  <br/>
  <input .... />
...
```

#### How do I do the above?

#### I tried:

inserting a `<br/>` in `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`:

```
config.label_text = lambda { |label, required| "#{required} #{label} <br/>" }
```

And this generates:

```
...
  <label>Email<br/></label>  #note the location of <br/>
  <input .... />
...
```

The `<br/>` is just before the `</label>`. Now, this works in terms of showing the input on the next "line", but it just feels "wrong".

Is there some way to do this properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's usually better to do this with stylesheet rules than by inserting HTML tags, since the break is a matter of formatting rather than of content.  It could be something as simple as...

```
label {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's not just opinion, but actually the  correct approach according to the HTML(5) spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-br-element.

Comment: Well, why did I not think of this? :)

Comment: It's OK -- we all have our moments <g>.

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree you should use css to do this as Steve described. But if you really want to, you can still do this by using rails' default form helper like so:

```
<%= f.label :email %>
<br>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
```